# Moment.JS display formatted time from named timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to display a time in the current named timezone using moment timezone.

The time is stored in the database in UTC as 2014-07-22 11:11:06. Whatever I try I cannot display the time as 12:11 even though the named timezone is Europe/London.

```
var timestamp = 1406023866000; // converted from database stored as UTC 2014-07-22 11:11:06
var zone = tz.name();          // Europe/London

var utc = moment(timestamp);   // create a moment from the timestamp
var time = utc.tz(zone);       // _d: Date {Tue Jul 22 2014 12:11:06 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)}
                               // _f: undefined
                               // _i: 1406023866000

formatted = time.format('h:mma');  // 11:11am - should be 12.11pm because of BST
```

Comment: Have you tried providing a string to tz.name?  Explicitly name your timezone?

Comment: Just tried that and made no difference `var time = utc.tz("Europe/London");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your timestamp is in milliseconds, 1406023866000 = GMT: Tue, 22 Jul 2014 10:11:06 GMT.

I used http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Changing the timezone in php from Europe/London to UTC seems to have fixed the issue somehow.

Comment: Congrats.  When I converted your timestamp - using the website above - the ceonverted date was ONE HOUR EARLIER than you posted in your question.  fyi

Comment: Yeh it was driving me crazy. I assumed that `date('U', strtotime($conversation_data['updated'])) * 1000;` was creating the timestamp in UTC.